# Powershell Azure AAD get total matching displayname

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

Hello Im new to powershell, I'm trying to increment a matching name that already exist and created inside AAD tenant.

For example if Test001 exist it should create Test002 in the Tenant. The logic behind is using Get-AzADUser and find similar displayName and output the count. After that I can just increment the number.

Here is my code so far to check the count that has matching case of displayname. However using filer or like doesn't allow me

```
$newAccount = (Get-AzADUser -like $matchcase)
write-host("Total number of Account:" + $newAccount.count)
```

instead received an error message

**Get-AzADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'like'.**

If I could get the matching total count then I can start incrementation

```
 $Num_identifier = [int]$identifiers
 $Num_identifier ++
```

Then format `"{0:d3}" -f $Num_identifier`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use `-like` to compare against a lists all AD users in a tenant if you don't specify what property to compare against.
Since all parameters for `Get-AzADUser` are Named, PowerShell tries to match whatever follows the cmdlet with one of the accepted parameter names and in this case that fails, hence the error message.

To find what you apparently seek, try this:

In this example, I assume the numeric suffix is added to the displayname as the last three digits.

```
# search for user displaynames with this regex pattern (see regex details below for explanation)
$matchcase = 'Glen Sale(\d{3})?$'
$existingUsers = @(Get-AzADUser | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $matchcase })
Write-Host "Total number of users with matching names: $($existingUsers.count))"
```

Next, sort these on the indexnumber and select the highest numbered object.
If there was no numeric suffix to the name, below expression will yield value 0

```
$lastUser  = $existingUsers | Sort-Object @{Expression = {[int]([regex]'\d{3}$').Match($_.DisplayName).Value}} | Select-Object -Last 1
# take the indexnumber from this user and increment
$nextIndex = [int]([regex]'\d{3}$').Match($lastUser.DisplayName).Value + 1
```

Now you can create a new user using this value formatted with leading zeroes up to three digits:

```
'Glen Sale{0:d3}' -f $nextIndex
```

Regex details:

```
Glen\ Sale     Match the characters “Glen Sale” literally
(              Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d          Match a single digit 0..9
      {3}      Exactly 3 times
)?             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$              Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```